# Como Activar un click Automáticamente al cargar la página

Tags: jquery

```
<nav class="menu">
                <ul>
                 <!-- ACCEDER -->
                   <?php
                     if(isset($_GET['acce']) && $_GET['acce']=="1"){
                   ?>
                        <li><a href="../index.php" onload="acceder();" class="acceder">ACCEDER</a></li>

                   <?php
                     }else {
                   ?>
                        <li><a class="acceder">ACCEDER</a></li>
                   <?php
                     }
                    ?>
                  <li><a href="php/acercaDe.php">ACERDA DE</a></li>
                </ul>
              </nav>
```

**Tratando de activar el click con un onload**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.acceder').click(function(){
        $('.all-paquetes').addClass('all-paquetesDesplasarFuera');
        $('.acceder-cont').addClass('acceder-cont-visual');
      });
      $('.flecha').click(function(){
        $('.acceder-cont').removeClass('acceder-cont-visual');
        $('.registro-cont').removeClass('registro-cont-visual');
        $('.all-paquetes').removeClass('all-paquetesDesplasarFuera');
        });
        $('.registrarme').click(function(){
          $('.acceder-cont').removeClass('acceder-cont-visual');
          $('.registro-cont').addClass('registro-cont-visual');

        window.onload=function acceder(){
          alert("mensaje");
          // $('.all-paquetes').addClass('all-paquetesDesplasarFuera');
          // $('.acceder-cont').addClass('acceder-cont-visual');
        }

        });
```

**Desde index.php**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
**Mostrando Login desde index**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
**Problema es si estoy desde acercaDe.php**
El problema esta cuando le doy click en acceder desde acercaDe.php; quiero que me lleve a index.php y active el click de acceder automaticamente del index.php
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Supongo que la primera pregunta debería ser: ¿para qué quieres hacer algo así? Si tienes un código que debe ejecutarse al cargar la página y al hacer click sobre un elemento, mete el código en una función y llama a esa función desde los controladores de ambos eventos.

Comment: ya se lo muestro en imagenes

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza trigger

```
$( ".acceder" ).trigger( "click" );
```

Comment: la pruebo y te aviso

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar solo con esto

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      // despues del código
      $('.acceder').click();
});
```